# add where clauses to linq query with generic column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to add where clauses to a linq query only if there is the column on the generic type table.

code example :
this function is generic for all tables in model. I want to add where condition for all the tabels that have "AccountId" column.

```
public IQueryable RetrieveAll(params Expression>[] eagerProperties) { 
var entitySet = ResolveEntitySet(typeof(T));
var query = context.CreateQuery<T>(entitySet);
foreach (var e in eagerProperties)
{
     query = query.Expand(e);
} 
var type = typeof(T); 
var account =    type.GetProperty("AccountId"); 
if(account!=null) 
  { 
    query = query.where(x=>x...) 
  } 
return query
```

I need something like

```
Guid g = new Guid("3252353h....")
query.where(x=>x.AccountId == g)
```

Thanks

Comment: I think it's a little unclear what you're asking. Can you edit your question with more explanations?

Comment: Well if you did "new Guid" on each call you'd always return null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must create the Where predicate dynamically using Expression Tree, look code below:

```
public static IQueryable<T> RetrieveAll<T>(params Expression[] eagerProperties)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var entitySet = ResolveEntitySet(type);
    var query = context.CreateQuery<T>(entitySet);
    foreach (var e in eagerProperties)
    {
        query = query.Expand(e);
    }
    var account = type.GetProperty("AccountId");
    if (account != null)
    {
        Guid g = new Guid("3252353h....");
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type);
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, account);
        var guidValue = Expression.Constant(g);

        var lambdaPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(property, guidValue), parameter);
        return query.Where(lambdaPredicate);
    }
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! you help me a lot